# term doesnt evaluate to 1 argument in std algorithm when using unary op defined with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am trying to use a `std::unique_ptr` functor in std algorithms but if i use it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<IFormatter> format(new formatter("abcd"));
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), *format.get())
```

I am getting compilation error saying:

> Error 1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.

Complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct IFormatter
{
protected:
    std::string keyFormat;
    void fun(std::string& str)
    {
        // do something here.
    }
public:
    IFormatter(std::string keyFormat) : keyFormat(keyFormat) {}
    virtual std::string operator() (const std::string &key) = 0;
};

struct formatter : IFormatter
{
    formatter(std::string keyFormat) : IFormatter(keyFormat) {}
    std::string operator() (const std::string &key)
    {
            std::string s = keyFormat;
            fun(s);
            return s;
    }
};

int main()
{        
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "one", "two" };
    std::unique_ptr<IFormatter> format(new formatter("$ID$"));
    // This line compiles fine if i define format as - formatter format("abcd");
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), format.get());
    start s;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks all for the suggestions but format.get() was a typo, I was using *format.get() & i had tried with *format (I agree that get() is not really needed.). Using std::ref(*format) isnt solving the problem. This is strange but i still gets same error.

P.S. IF it matters i am using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Quick guess: try `*format.get()`. A pointer to a `formatter` is not callable. A reference to a `formatter` *is* callable.

Comment: @BoBTFish: `.get()` is unneeded, `*format` is enough and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), std::ref(*format));
```

A pointer isn't callable. But you have a pointer-to-base, so `std::ref` to avoid slicing.

---

Since MSVC 2013's `reference_wrapper` [hates abstract classes](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/828696), use a lambda:

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
               [&](const std::string& s) { return (*format)(s); });
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning slicing. I had missed that part. but original problem is still as is.

Comment: @user888270 Ah, [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/828696).